# How to load the jquery lib on visual studio 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I get this error.

> SCRIPT5009: Unhandled exception at line 2, column 1 in ms-appx://f224cbf1-ee2e-466c-9748-7b34d7e619a2/js/main.js
>   0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

And this is my index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App1</title>

    <script src="Assets/Libs/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"     rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Works</h1>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure you want to load both a local jquery 3.1.1 **and** a remote jquery 1.4.2? two very different versions of jQuery at the same time seems to be an odd thing to do

Comment: no i just test if the remote jquery work but is not workink